# Quicksort complexities in depth

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort, partition, logarithm

So I am having an exam, and a big part of this exam will be quicksort algorithm. As everyone knows, the best case scenario and actually an average case for this algorithm is: `O(nlogn)`. The worst case scenario would be `O(n^2)`.

As for the worst case scenario I know how to explain it: It happens when the selected pivot would be the smallest or the biggest value in the array, then we would have `n` quicksort calls which may take up to `n` time (I mean partition operation). Am I right?

Now the best/average case. I've read the Cormens book, I understood many things thanks to that book, but as for the quicksort algorithm he focuses on the mathematical formulas on how to explain `O(nlogn)` complexity. I just wanted to know why is it `O(nlogn)`, not getting into some mathematical proof. For now I've only seen some Wikipedia explanation, that if we choose a pivot which divides our array into `n/2, n/2+1` parts each time, then we would have a call tree of depth `logn`, but I don't know if that is true and even if so, why is it `logn` then.

I know that there are many materials covering quicksort on the internet, but they only cover implementation, or are just telling me the complexity, not explaining it.

Comment: Do you understand what log2 is?  Do you understand the effect of splitting the remaining work in half with each level of recursion?

Comment: Yes, I have to find a number `k` such as `2^k=n`

Comment: Yes, so if you go n, n/2, n/4, n/8, ..., there would be, by definition, log2(n) terms.

Comment: And each one takes `n` time, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right?

Yes.

> we would have a call tree of depth `logn` but I don't know if that is true

It is.

> why is it `logn`?

Because we partition the array in half at every step, resulting in `logn` depth of the call graph. From this [Intro](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap08.htm):

[image]

See the tree and its depth, it's `logn`. Imagine it as the search in a BST costs `logn`, or why search takes `logn` too in Binary search in a sorted array.

---

PS: Math tell the truth, invest in understanding them, and you shall become a better Computer Scientist! =)

Answer (score 1):

For the best case scenario, quick sort splits the current array 50% / 50% (in half) on each partition step for a time complexity of O(log2(n)) (1/.5 = 2), but the constant 2 is ignored, so it's O(n log(n).

If each partition step produced a 20% / 80% split, then the worst case time complexity would be based on the 80% or O(n log1.25(n)) (1/.8 = 1.25), but the constant 1.25 is ignored so it's also O(n log(n)), even though it's about 3 times slower than the 50% / 50% partition case for sorting 1 million elements.

The O(n^2) time complexity occurs when the partition split only produces a linear reduction in partition size with each partition step. The simplest and worst case example is when only 1 element is removed per partition step.